# Сравнение идентичных строк даёт False

Tags: node.js

```
var str = 'ertuyuiertyu';

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          resolve(data.toString());
        };
      });
    });

    promise.then(
      result => {
        if (result === str) {
          console.log(true);
        }
        else {
          console.log(false);
        }
      }
    );
```

В File.txt записана данная строка - "ertuyuiertyu" в кодировке UTF-8. Как вы заметили в коде есть такая же строка. После чтения файла, в блоке я сравниваю эти строки, и всегда значение false. Строки совершенно идентичны, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: поменяйте на `resolve(str)`, каким будет значение?

Comment: Переносы строк в файле есть? В `promise.then` выведите в консоль `result`. Что там?

Comment: ...или другие непечатные символы?

Comment: Поменял на resolve(str), вывело разумеется true. В файле переносов нет. Строго строка.

Comment: А так? `resolve(data.toString().replace('\uFEFF', ''));`

Comment: Yaant, получился false

Comment: Непонятно зачем тут toString. И вангую, что там таки есть перевод строки. Попробуйте длину строк сравнить. Ещё может в одной из этих строк кириллица затесалась?

Comment: toString буффер в строку конвертирует.

Comment: Дело было в длине строк, спасибо!

Comment: @BadProgrammer только у вас уже строка раз кодировка указана

Comment: Т.е. таки разные строки. ЧТД

Comment: И, кстати, в случае ошибки надо не кидать исключение, а вызывать reject, раз уж вы сюда зачем-то промизы добавили

Comment: @Yaant, то, FFFE - это BOM для UTF16, а у него UTF8.

Comment: @Qwertiy так-то да, но я этот вариант лично проверил на файле UTF-8 with BOM, и получил `true`. :) Где-то вчера видел, но сейчас с ходу не найду, что нода делает какое-то преобразование при чтении. **Upd:** Что-то нашел: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757557/why-does-node-js-convert-bom-character-to-0xfe-0xff

Comment: @Yaant, да, ты прав. Код из моего ответа и есть `\uFEFF`. Почему-то я не сравнивал...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в UTF8 BOM. Попробуй так:

```
const str = 'ertuyuiertyu';

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(data.charCodeAt(0) === 65279 ? data.substr(1) : data);
    };
  });
});

promise.then(
  result => {
    console.log(result === str);
  }
);
```